# How to cut properly a slab from a cif file?

Tags: crystal-structure, density-functional-theory, crystallography

I am trying to do DFT calculations on ethanol adsorbed on Pd, both surfaces 111 and 100. I have the `cif` file from the database and also I have built the new unit cell that explicitly shows face 111.

I need to slab of Pd, one of 100, the other 111, made by 5 layers of metal, 9 atoms per layer. I have tried with `VESTA` (with this software I have obtained the new unit cell), but I cannot reproduce the slabs from the reference article, both in number and in geometry. Do you have a sort of guide/recipe idiot-proof to prepare correctly a slab for DFT simulations?

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! We hope to see much more of you here in the future!!! I saw your attempt to edit one of our questions here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1106. Instead, why don't you answer this one: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/16726/27342?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [ASE.](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/)

- For your case, I assume you are using the [Pd crystal structure with space group 225.](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-2/#)

[image]

- Cut the (111) surface with ASE:

  ```
  from ase.io import read, write
  from ase.build import surface

  ####================================================
  A=read('Pd_mp-2_conventional_standard.cif',format='cif')
  B=surface(A,(1,1,1),5,vacuum=10)
  write('111.vasp',B,format='vasp')
  ```
- The 111 slab with five atomic layers:

[image]

To obtain 9 atoms in each layer you may need to make a matrix transformation with `VESTA`.

Hope it helps.